# Variable assignment in TensorFlow gives error

Tags: tensorflow

If I have a placeholder:

```
placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[1, 2])
```

And then I create an op which assigns the placeholder to a new variable `y`:

```
y = tf.Variable([[0, 0]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_op = tf.assign(y, placeholder)
```

Then specify a value which I will feed into this placeholder:

```
x = tf.Variable([[5, 5]], dtype=np.float32)
```

And finally run the operation:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(y_op, feed_dict={placeholder: x})
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Why is this? From what I can see, the shapes of `placeholder`, `y`, and `x`, are all `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to feed a graph variable using the feed dict. Feed dict and placeholders are for feeding external values into the graph. This code works:

```
placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[1, 2])
y = tf.Variable([[0, 0]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_op = tf.assign(y, placeholder)

value = np.array([[5,5]])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
r = sess.run(y_op, feed_dict={placeholder: value})
```

But if the value you want to use in the graph is already a tf.Variable, there is no reason to use feed dict at all. This also works:

```
x = tf.Variable([[5, 5]], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable([[0, 0]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_op = tf.assign(y, x)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
r = sess.run(y_op)
```